# Why wasn't Harry Potter home schooled?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, jk-rowling

I am wondering if there is a canon explanation for Harry Potter being sent to Hogwarts for his wizarding education instead of being home schooled by professors at a safe place, such as one that would be constantly guarded by the members of the Order of the Phoenix. I am curious to know if this was ever brought to J.K. Rowling's attention and what her response was.

Wouldn't it be logical that Professor Dumbledore and the members of the Order of the Phoenix would have foreseen that Harry's life would always be in jeopardy living in a wide-open environment such as Hogwarts?

Plus, wouldn't they have also foreseen that Harry would possibly go exploring the areas around Hogwarts and this would put him in even greater jeopardy since the Death Eaters and Lord Voldemort would always be looking for opportunities to kill him?

Why wasn't Harry Potter home schooled?

Comment: When the series started was there any reason to think he was at risk?

Comment: @JoeW, well the prophecy said that he would be the one to kill Lord Voldemort so this means that he would eventually meet up with Voldemort, in fact, he faced off against the spirit of Voldemort in the first film, The Sorcerer's Stone.

Comment: Most people did not know of that prophecy and assumed that he was dead and gone forever. There where only a select few who believed otherwise.

Comment: @JoeW, that's why I'm wondering why Prof. Dumbledore didn't decide to home school Harry since he knew of the prophecy.

Comment: If people thought that Voldemort was dead would they really approve of the headmaster of hogwarts homeschooling a student that is not his child? Since Harry's parents where dead and he was living with non magical relatives homeschooling was not an option

Comment: @JoeW, I think that is a question for J.K. Rowling to answer. Perhaps she has already done so but I haven't seen it.

Comment: Well since Dumbledore lived at Hogwarts didn't he technically? Plus I'm pretty sure it was said a few times that there was no safer place than Hogwarts. Also, even if neither those things were the case, Dumbledore as the headmaster of Hogwarts was a pretty busy dude, he couldn't just spend all his time looking after Harry and he would have basically been ignoring all the other people he was looking out for at the same time.

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle, I think that the most logical thing to do would have been to place Harry at a secret location/house used only by the members of the Order of the Phoneix. Different professors within this Order would come out to that location to teach Harry different wizarding skills.

Comment: How well did going to a secret location work out for his parents?

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle, that wasn't a magically hidden house. It was located in the muggle world for everyone to see and walk up to.

Comment: @user255577 I read in another post that Dumbledore had placed a protection spell that prevented Voldemort from harming Harry in the house before he turned 17 as long as he lived there, which is why they had to leave at the beginning of the last book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Hogwarts was one of the safest places.

Going to Hogwarts would not have been considered unsafe for Harry since Voldemort never attacked Hogwarts during his first rise to power.

> “Terrible things happened. He was takin’ over. ’Course, some stood up to him – an’ he killed ’em. Horribly. One o’ the only safe places left was Hogwarts. Reckon Dumbledore’s the only one You-Know-Who was afraid of. Didn’t dare try takin’ the school, not jus’ then, anyway.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 4 (The Keeper of the Keys)*</sup></sub>

Hagrid referred to Gringotts as the best place for keeping things safe, and says Hogwarts may possibly be even better than Gringotts. Harry is also something Dumbledore wanted kept safe, so it would be logical to want him at Hogwarts.

> “Gringotts is the safest place in the world fer anything yeh want ter keep safe – ’cept maybe Hogwarts.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 5 (Diagon Alley)*</sup></sub>

While Voldemort did attempt to get at Harry indirectly when Harry was at Hogwarts, until Dumbledore’s death, he avoided going near Hogwarts himself except when he possessed Quirrell. Voldemort did not even consider attempting to get Harry at Hogwarts a viable option.

> “I thought his protection might be weaker there, away from his relations and Dumbledore, but I was not yet strong enough to attempt kidnap in the midst of a horde of Ministry wizards. And then, the boy would return to Hogwarts, where he is under the crooked nose of that Muggle-loving fool from morning until night. So how could I take him?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

Since clearly Voldemort did not see direct attacks on Hogwarts as an option, considering Dumbledore’s protection there an impossible obstacle to get past, it was indeed quite safe to keep Harry at Hogwarts.

## Hogwarts is considered the best school.

While homeschooling was allowed, Hogwarts was thought to be the best education a young wizard could get.

> “Attendance is now compulsory for every young witch and wizard,’ he replied. ‘That was announced yesterday. It’s a change, because it was never obligatory before. Of course, nearly every witch and wizard in Britain has been educated at Hogwarts, but their parents had the right to teach them at home or send them abroad if they preferred.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11 (The Bribe)*</sup></sub>

Hagrid called it the finest school of witchcraft and wizardry in the world.

> “Stop Lily an’ James Potter’s son goin’ ter Hogwarts! Yer mad. His name’s been down ever since he was born. He’s off ter the finest school of witchcraft and wizardry in the world. Seven years there and he won’t know himself. He’ll be with youngsters of his own sort, fer a change, an’ he’ll be under the greatest Headmaster Hogwarts ever had, Albus Dumbled–” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 4 (The Keeper of the Keys)*</sup></sub>

Though Dumbledore wanted to protect Harry, Harry eventually would have to face Voldemort, so it would be extremely important for him to have a proper magical education.

Comment: I see your point. I guess that Harry having the best education will give him the greatest chance of defeating Voldemort when they would eventually face one another.

Comment: @user255577 Exactly, and since Voldemort feared Dumbledore, Voldemort avoided Hogwarts, making it a relatively safe place for Harry.

Comment: Also, do they even _do_ Homeschooling/Distance-Ed?

Comment: @Möoz Yes, Lupin references being taught at home as an option in Deathly Hallows. *“Of course, nearly every witch and wizard in Britain has been educated at Hogwarts, but their parents had the right to teach them at home or send them abroad if they preferred.” - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11 (The Bribe)*

Comment: @Möoz Both homeschooling and correspondence courses are mentioned in the JKR writing about wizarding schools on the Wizarding World website. *“The number of countries that have their own magical school is minuscule compared to those that do not. This is because the wizarding populations of most countries choose the option of home schooling. Occasionally, too, the magical community in a given country is tiny or far-flung and correspondence courses have been found a more cost-effective means of educating the young. - Wizarding Schools (wizardingworld.com)*

Comment: @Mal [Ineresting](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/515/121/dfd.jpg)

Comment: @Möoz Thanks! :)